# Add specific files to master branch

Tags: git, github

I have created a new branch called “new_functionality” by using the following command.

```
git checkout -b new_functionality
```

Now I have modified the following files in my project.

1. Configuration files ( lets take c1,c2,c3 files ) - need to be change to make sure that local deployment happened successfully.
2. Some project files ( lets take file1, file2, file3 ) – these are the files I have worked to incorporate the functionality change in my project.
   Now after confirming with the functional changes, I have to push these modified files to remote. 
   So what I have done.

I have added files in following format

```
git add file1
git add file2
git add file3
```

and then committed the changes like

```
git commit -m “files changed”.
```

After committing the changes locally I have pushed the code by following syntax.

```
git push -u origin  new_functionality
```

what happened:

I have verified the remote repo, and all the files c1,c2,c3,file1,file2,file3 were present in the branch I have pushed.

What I want

I want only file1, file2, file3 to present in the new_functionality branch at remote repo.

Kindly suggest me the ways to achieve the desired functionality.

Comment: recommended reading: **[Where does my git question go?](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/6311/where-does-my-git-question-go)**

Comment: It sounds like the real problem here could be that "Configuration files" that can affect local building are in Git, and thus you want different config files in different branches? Generally ppl try not to check config files into source control at all.